# VSCode : possible to synchronize scroll in column view?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can VSCode display text "newspaper style," with text flowing over into the next column?

**Use case: view what would ordinarily be multiple pages, but at once, in sync.**

```
This      ...that         Yay for
is        continues       using my
some      in the          wide
text...   next column!    monitor.
```

**And if you scroll:**

```
           some           in the
           text...        next column!
This       ...that        Yay for
is         continues      using my
```

Comment: Top right corner of the code window is a "Split Editor" button. ◫

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Right, but the columns don't scroll in sync; they're independent -- please see edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible via the Under Scroll extension.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GiorgosXou.under-scroll

It's a bit buggy -- I've found that it's happier with keyboard scrolling (following the cursor) than mouse scrolling, where the window scrolls but the cursor stays in place.

But nevertheless, when you need to read a lot of code, it really makes good use of your horizontal screen space.

Comment: I assume you found some of the posts I've been interacting with? duplicates should be closed instead of answered.